# How to tell QGIS where to start marker line interval?

Tags: qgis, symbology, markers

I  want to tell QGIS where to start with a marker, like: use 3 markers, start at positions 0, 2, 4, and apply an interval of 12 to each marker.

However, after searching for hours, I haven't found a way to deal with this issue.

[image]

## EDIT:

Regardings Nathan's answer:
This happens if x-offset for markers is used:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You sure can.

First you need to add a Marker symbol to your line symbol and stack the symbols like so:

[image]

- The first Simple Marker has a X offset of 0
- The second Simple Marker
  has a X offset of 2
- The third Simple Marker has a X offset of 4

Click on the Marker Line symbol layer and set the with interval value to what ever looks good

[image]

Comment: This will only work for a straight line - if the line bends, the offsetted markers will not align along the line! See the image in the post-edit.

Comment: It would be good to have an option "offset along line".

Comment: So, it is not possible? I couldn't imagine that..

Comment: Yes it's a known issue.

Comment: Do you know if there are any feature requests regarding this? - I really want to push this, as it seems to me as a very basic feature!

Comment: Cheerio! ..QGIS 2.6 has new feature 'Offset along line'!

Answer (score 3):

I just found a workaround which works for single color simple markers, using a custom dash pattern with round cap style and 0,0001 long dashes, which will look like dots:

[image]

Damnit, this was a hard one..